# Image Picker from gallery or camera is not opening when clicking the bottomSheet icons - flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am building a registration screen and it is asking the user to choose a profile picture which is implemented inside the CircleAvatar widget, when the user clicks the avatar a bottomSheet appears with Camera Icon and Gallery icon to provide options for the user to select the image, now when i click on the camera icon or the image icon the picker is not showing, here is the CircleAvatar implementation inside a custom widget i build called imageProfile() :

```
File? image;
  //Creating a new custom widget called imageProfile.
  Widget imageProfile() {
    //stack is a widget used as a wrapper, this wrapper places the elements on top of each other like the stack of books.
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        shape: BoxShape.circle,
        border: Border.all(
          color: Colors.purple,
          width: 4.0,
        ),
      ),
      child: Center(
        child: Stack(
          // ignore: prefer_const_literals_to_create_immutables
          children: <Widget>[
            // ignore: prefer_const_constructors
            CircleAvatar(
              radius: 80.0,
              backgroundImage: AssetImage("assets/DefaultImage.png"),
            ),
            Positioned(
              bottom: 20,
              right: 20,
              child: InkWell(
                  onTap: () {
                    showModalBottomSheet(
                        context: context,
                        builder: ((builder) => bottomSheet()));
                  },
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.camera_alt,
                    size: 28,
                  )),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

When the user clicks the Avatar icon a custom bottomSheet widget appears normally which implemented as follows:

```
//Designing the bottom sheet that appears when clicking the profile image icon to choose from either gallery or take a photo
  Widget bottomSheet() {
    return Container(
      height: 200,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 20),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            'Choose Profile Picture',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Column(
                children: [
                  IconButton(
                    iconSize: 70,
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.camera),
                    onPressed: () {
                      Future pickImage() async {
                        final image = await ImagePicker()
                            .pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
                        if (image == null) return;

                        final imageTemporary = File(image.path);
                        setState(() => this.image = imageTemporary);
                      }
                    },
                  ),
                  Text('Camera')
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: 50,
              ),
              Column(
                children: [
                  IconButton(
                    iconSize: 70,
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.image),
                    onPressed: () {
                      pickImage() async {
                        final image = await ImagePicker()
                            .pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
                        if (image == null) return;

                        final imageTemporary = File(image.path);
                        setState(() => this.image = imageTemporary);
                      }
                    },
                  ),
                  Text('Gallery'),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

in the Scaffold the elements or widgets are rendered as follows:

```
return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Center(
        //Use the SingleChildScrollView as a wrapper to ensure scrolling in case scorrling is needed.
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          //wrap the elements with Container to provide flexibility in designing the elements.
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.white,
            //use the form as a container of the input fields as it is a login form.
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(36.0),
              child: Form(
                //give the form wrapper the key value to tell flutter that this is the form design for your form functions.
                key: _formKey,
                //use the column to show the elements in vertical array.
                child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    //Use children property inside the column to specify list of widgets
                    children: <Widget>[
                      imageProfile(),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 20,
                      ),
                    ]),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

and i haven't forgot the packages added in the pubspec.yaml file and imported in the registration screen:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:datetime_picker_formfield/datetime_picker_formfield.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
```

i am not sure why its not opening and what i am missing as its not showing any errors, i would be thankful for any help

Comment: Have you also added permission in manifest and plist?

Comment: i actually havn't but if you could please provide me an article that explains the approach if it did works ill let you know to post it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used your part of your code and add *the pick image function*.
Each button will trigger different functions and show correctly.

Could you try my code or extract code inside onPressed() as a new function again?

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';


class photoPicker extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String id = 'photoPicker_screen';

  const photoPicker({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<photoPicker> createState() => _photoPickerState();
}

class _photoPickerState extends State<photoPicker> {
  File? image;
  String image2 ='images/img.png';
  
  void selectImage() async {
    final ImagePicker imagePicker = ImagePicker();
    final XFile? selectedImage = await imagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    print(selectedImage?.path);
    setState(() {
      var a = selectedImage?.path;
      image2 = a!;
    }
    );
  }

  void selectImagesCamera() async {
    final ImagePicker imagePicker = ImagePicker();
    final XFile? selectedImage = await imagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
    print(selectedImage?.path);
    setState(() {
      var a = selectedImage?.path;
      image2 = a!;

    }
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'Choose Profile Picture',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Column(
                  children: [
                    IconButton(
                      iconSize: 70,
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.camera),
                      onPressed: () {
                        selectImagesCamera();
                      },
                    ),
                    Text('Camera')
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 50,
                ),
                Column(
                  children: [
                    IconButton(
                      iconSize: 70,
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.image),
                      onPressed: () {
                        selectImage();
                      },
                    ),
                    Text('Gallery'),
                  ],
                ),

              ],
            ),
            Container(
              height: 120.0,
              width: 120.0,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: AssetImage(
                      image2
                  ),
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                ),
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Fig1. Main Screen
[image]
Fig2. Camera Mode
[image]
[image]
Fig3. Gallery Mode
[image]

Comment: I will try your code and update you thank you for answer

Comment: @editix I've modified my code which is possible to replace the image with the image from two different modes.

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer is complete

Answer (score 1):

Because you defined the function but not get it called, try replace open camera code with:

```dart
                      Future pickImage() async {
                        final image = await ImagePicker()
                            .pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
                        if (image == null) return;

                        final imageTemporary = File(image.path);
                        setState(() => this.image = imageTemporary);
                      }

                      pickImage();
```

the open gallery code is with the same problem.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer it actually worked, but its not updating the state of the profile image could you please take a look at that

Answer (score 1):

The bottom sheet does not update on set state unless it is a stateful widget. Wrap the content of bottom sheet with a statefulbuilder

```
Widget bottomSheet() {
return StatefulBuilder(
        builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState) {
          return Container(); //add bottom sheet container here
       }
  );
}
```

And the on pressed should look like this

```
onPressed: () async {
 image = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
      if (image == null) return;

      final imageTemporary = File(image.path);
                        setState(() => this.image = imageTemporary);
   }
```

And declare variable above the build method.

```
XFile? Image;
```

Now your have the image inside the on pressed event which is not accessible by other widgets

Comment: Thanks for answering but actually it didn't work ill try to handle the permissions first in the manifest and plist files first then ill try again

Comment: i have actually used your solution with some other editing and its working but the problem now after i choose a picture or take picture from the camera it is not replacing the default picture i set

Comment: Which is the default picture?